# Chrome auto populate won't trip bootstrap-acknowledgeinput NOR jqBootstrapValidation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I use bootstrap-acknowledgeinput to make those nice checkmarks and found jqBootstrapValidatin as well, I use a two-stage browser validation, bootstrap-acknowledgeinput makes sure the field is not blank and jqBootstrapValidatin handles true validation and REGEX patterns and adds a  below the form field in brown text which
gives the error.

BUT in Chrome when I put in my address and all the form fields auto populate, my validation
doesn't appear to run until I go to each input field at the end and hit [enter].  Anybody
else run into this?  Is there a way to trap when autocomplete finishes and go to those
fields it filled in and programically "hit [enter]"   Anybody fixed this issue?

I use backbone, requirejs, twitter bootstrap

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'lib/jquery-migrate-1.2.1',
    'models/RegisterModel',
    'text!templates/RegisterTemplate.html',
    'lib/jquery.maskedinput-1.0',
    'lib/bootstrap-acknowledgeinput.min',
    'lib/jqBootstrapValidation'
], function ($, _, Backbone, jQueryMigrate, RegisterModel, RegisterTemplate, MaskedInput, Ack, jqAck) {

    var RegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $("#container"),

        events: {
            'click .btn-primary': 'saveClient',
            'blur input#loginname': 'userCheck'
        },

        render: function () {

            //Since our template has dynamic variables in it, we need to compile it
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(RegisterTemplate, this.model);
            this.$el.html(compiledTemplate); 

            this.$('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');
            this.$('#phone2').mask('(999) 999-9999');
            this.$('#zip').mask('99999');

            $(function () {
                $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation();
            });

            $().acknowledgeinput({
                success_color: '#00FF00',
                danger_color: '#FF0000',
                update_on: 'keyup'
            });
```